# am i able to run the same program anywhere?

Tags: windows, command-prompt, windows-firewall

I want to create a program to track hours, ex. for a job or service hours, that would work on any computer. Is that possible? I don't want to have to download a compiler on every computer, so I was thinking there might be some way to run it in command prompt (on windows, since all the computers I use are windows). I was also wondering, if the program will run without a compiler, can I just carry it around on a flash drive and copy it to whatever device I'm using?

The program would take a user's name and password, check if both are right, then let them add a new entry or change previous entries. This way all of their data is accessible (sort of like a database).

I want to be able to run it without downloading a compiler (because of organizational firewalls, etc.), otherwise it might be a bit more complicated. Is there any way to achieve this?

I haven't really tried anything yet, just doing some preliminary research before I commit.

Comment: A compiler makes an EXE / executable.  Once you have that, you do not need the complier.  So yes, you can carry that EXE around on a USB stick and run it on other PCs.  Note that the security software on your work PC might block this.  Also, the data files need to be on the USB stick too, because data is not shared across every PC you use.  An alternative is to get a cheap server somewhere like Amazon or Azure and build web software to do this.  Go to the web server from any PC without needing local software.

Comment: "The program would take a user's name and password, check if both are right, then let them add a new entry or change previous entries. This way all of their data is accessible (sort of like a database)" - Perhaps not directly related to what your original question is, but - I see a couple of issues with your setup. In order to be able to do any kind of comparison (user entry vs *some expected values*), you would need to have those *expected values* stored somewhere (ini / configuration file, registry, local or LAN or outside network database, etc). So your problem is not only getting your ->

Comment: -> application compiled and tested on various Windows versions and configurations, it is also tied to resolving the issue of storing user credentials, and the issue of whether you'd allow a user who's not normally using another user's PC to enter their credentials via your application on a PC which is not theirs. So, as @DaveS mentioned, an alternative to all of this is migrating your application to a web server (or a local server, accessible by all users within the organization using your software).